# How do I display only the months names only once on a years worth of data on an MVC kendo line chart

Tags: charts, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to show 365 results on a kendo line chart but as so many results cause label overlaps, I would like to display each month name only once on the category axis

```
          @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.Totals)
                .Name("totalChart")
                .Title("Total Daily")
                .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
                .Series
                (
                    series => series
                        .Line(model => model.Total)
                        .Style(ChartLineStyle.Smooth)
                        .Color("#42a7ff")
                        .Name("Date")                           
                )
                .Events
                (
                    e => e
                      .SeriesClick("ChartClick")
                )
                .CategoryAxis
                (
                    axis => axis
                        .Categories(model => model.Date)
                        .Labels
                        (
                            labels => labels
                              .Rotation(45)
                              .Visible(true)
                              .Template("#= kendo.toString(value,'MM') #")
                        )
                        .Title("This Month")      
                )
                .ValueAxis
                (
                    axis => axis
                      .Numeric()
                      .MajorUnit(10)
                )
                .Tooltip
                (
                 tooltip => tooltip
                   .Visible(true)
                   .Template("#= value # | #= category #")
                   .Background("#ffffff")
                )
          )
```

I have used the base unit parameter but this then only displays 12 results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. If you set the axis to Date(), the step to the maximum number of days(31):

```
  .CategoryAxis
  (
      axis => axis
          .Date()
          .Categories(model => model.Date)
          .Labels
          (
              labels => labels 
                  .Visible(true)
                  .Template("#= kendo.toString(value,'MMMM') #")
                  .Step(31)
                  .Padding(0,0,0,120)
          )
          .Title("All the months")      
  )
```